# A star implementation in C++ (Language Issues)

Tags: c++, algorithm, debugging, pointers, overloading

I am working on an A star algorithm to solve an N tile slide puzzle. Give a particular goal state I want to find the least number of steps to solve it. I understand the algorithm but I am having issues with C++ due to my lack of understanding. Any style suggestions would be greatly appreciated as well.

- Overload Operator Assignment: seems like there is a problem with deleting elements pointer, so right now I am manually reassigning everything
- browseNeighbor: seems to do everything I want it to but the data that gets pushed back onto the open vector the values in elements seem to get jumbled when it is accessed again in the solve function.
- Right now I am only letting it access leftIndex to perform move left and giving it a really simple problem to solve to see if it works, but the two issues above prevent it from working right.

C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class board{
    public:
        int boardSize;
        int *elements; //ptr to array
        int rowSize;
        int zeroIndex;
        int upIndex;
        int downIndex;
        int leftIndex;
        int rightIndex;
        int h;
        int g;
        int f;
        board();
        board(int new_rowSize, int new_elements[]);
        ~board();
        void updateZero();
        void updateUpIndex();
        void updateDownIndex();
        void updateLeftIndex();
        void updateRightIndex();
        void updateIndexes();
        void moveUp();
        void moveDown();
        void moveLeft();
        void moveRight();
        bool operator==(const board&);
        board& operator=(const board&);
};
board::board(){
    rowSize = 3;
    boardSize = rowSize * rowSize;
    elements = new int[boardSize];
}
board::board(int new_rowSize, int new_elements[]){
    rowSize = new_rowSize;
    boardSize = rowSize * rowSize;
    elements = new int[boardSize];
    for(int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
        elements[i] = new_elements[i];
    }
}
board::~board(){
    delete [] elements;
}
void board::updateZero(){
    for(int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++){
        if(elements[i] == 0) {
            zeroIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
void board::updateUpIndex(){
    int temp_upIndex = zeroIndex + rowSize;
    if (temp_upIndex < boardSize) {
        upIndex = temp_upIndex;
    }
    else {
        upIndex = -1;
    }
}
void board::updateDownIndex(){
    int temp_downIndex = zeroIndex - rowSize;
    if (temp_downIndex >= 0) {
        downIndex = temp_downIndex;
    }
    else {
        downIndex = -1;
    }
}
void board::updateLeftIndex(){
    int temp_leftIndex = zeroIndex + 1;
    if(temp_leftIndex % rowSize != 0) {
        leftIndex = temp_leftIndex;
    }
    else {
        leftIndex = -1;
    }
}
void board::updateRightIndex(){
    int temp_rightIndex = zeroIndex - 1;
    if(zeroIndex >= 0 && temp_rightIndex % rowSize - 1 != 0) {
        rightIndex = temp_rightIndex;
    }
    else {
        rightIndex = -1;
    }
}
void board::updateIndexes(){
    updateZero();
    updateUpIndex();
    updateDownIndex();
    updateLeftIndex();
    updateRightIndex();
}
bool board::operator==(const board& second){
    bool result = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++){
        if(elements[i] != second.elements[i])
            result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
void board::moveUp(){
    elements[zeroIndex] = elements[upIndex];
    elements[upIndex] = 0;
}
void board::moveDown(){
    elements[zeroIndex] = elements[downIndex];
    elements[downIndex] = 0;
}
void board::moveLeft(){
    elements[zeroIndex] = elements[leftIndex];
    elements[leftIndex] = 0;
}
void board::moveRight(){
    elements[zeroIndex] = elements[rightIndex];
    elements[rightIndex] = 0;
}
board& board::operator=(const board& rhs){
    if(this != &rhs){
        delete [] elements;
        boardSize = rhs.boardSize;
        rowSize = rhs.rowSize;

        elements = new int[boardSize];
        for(int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
            elements[i] = rhs.elements[i];
        } 

        zeroIndex = rhs.zeroIndex;
        upIndex = rhs.upIndex;
        downIndex = rhs.downIndex;
        leftIndex = rhs.leftIndex;
        rightIndex = rhs.rightIndex;
        h = rhs.h;
        g = rhs.g;
        f = rhs.f;
    }
    return *this;
}

int manhattan(board *goal, board *current){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < goal->boardSize; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < current->boardSize; j++) {
            if(goal->elements[i] == current->elements[j]) {
                //this produces (goal.x - current.x) + (goal.y - current.y)
                sum += abs(i%goal->rowSize - j%goal->rowSize) + abs(i/goal->rowSize - j/goal->rowSize);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return sum;
}

void browseNeighbor(board *goal, board *x, vector<board *> *open, vector<board *> *closed){
            //check if in closed
            x->updateIndexes();
            for(int i = 0; i < closed->size(); i++){
                if(x == closed->at(i)) {
                    return;
                }
            }

            int tenative_g = x->g + 1;
            //check if not in opn
            //flag for in or not
            bool in_open = false;
            int open_index = -1;
            for(int i = 0;  i < open->size(); i++){
                if(x == open->at(i)){
                    in_open = true;
                    open_index = i;
                }
            }
            //cout << "The value of in open is " << in_open << endl;
            bool tenative_is_better = false;
            if(in_open == false) {
                //open->push_back(x);
                tenative_is_better = true;
            }
            else if(tenative_g < x->g){
                tenative_is_better = true;
            }
            else {
                //tenative_is_better = false;
                return;
            }
            if(tenative_is_better == true){
                //how to update correctly
                //if just placed than access in_open.back()
                //if not placed, find it in open
                if(in_open == false){
                    x->g = tenative_g;
                    x->h = manhattan(goal,x);
                    x->f = x->g + x->h;
                    open->push_back(x);
                }
                else{
                    open->at(open_index)->g = tenative_g;
                    open->at(open_index)->h = manhattan(goal,x);
                    open->at(open_index)->f = open->at(open_index)->g + open->at(open_index)->h;
                }
            }
}
void solve(board *goal, board *current){
    vector<board *> closed;
    vector<board *> open;
    //Initialize values of current
    current->g = 0;
    current->h = manhattan(goal,current);
    current->f = current->h;
    open.push_back(current);

    while(!open.empty()){
        //find entry in open with the lowest f value
        int lowest_index = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < open.size(); i++) {
            if(open[i]->f < open[lowest_index]->f) {
                lowest_index = i;
            }
        }

        board *x = open[lowest_index];
        board temp(x->rowSize, x->elements); 
        //board temp = *x;
        temp.boardSize = x->boardSize;
        temp.zeroIndex = x->zeroIndex;
        temp.upIndex = x->upIndex;
        temp.downIndex = x->downIndex;
        temp.leftIndex = x->leftIndex;
        temp.rightIndex = x->rightIndex;
        temp.g = x->g;
        temp.h = x->h;
        temp.f = x->f;
        x = &temp;
        x->updateIndexes();

        printf("The value of x is  \n");
        for(int i = 0; i < x->boardSize; i++){
            printf("%d", x->elements[i]);
        }
        cout << endl;
        //stop if the goal has been reached
        if(x->h == goal->h) {
            //return answer
            return;
        }

        closed.push_back(x);
        open.erase(open.begin()+lowest_index);
        /*if(x->upIndex >= 0){
            board *y = x;
            board temp_y(y->rowSize, y->elements);
            y = &temp_y;
            y->moveUp();
            browseNeighbor(goal, y, &open, &closed);
        }
        if(x->downIndex >= 0){
            board *y = x;
            board temp_y(y->rowSize, y->elements);
            y = &temp_y;
            y->moveDown();
            browseNeighbor(goal, y, &open, &closed);
        }
        */
        if(x->leftIndex >= 0){
            board *y = x;
            board temp_y(y->rowSize, y->elements);// = *y;
            temp_y.boardSize = y->boardSize;
            temp_y.zeroIndex = y->zeroIndex;
            temp_y.upIndex = y->upIndex;
            temp_y.downIndex = y->downIndex;
            temp_y.leftIndex = y->leftIndex;
            temp_y.rightIndex = y->rightIndex;
            temp_y.g = y->g;
            temp_y.h = y->h;
            temp_y.f = y->f;
            y = &temp_y;
            y->moveLeft();

            y->updateIndexes();
            browseNeighbor(goal, y, &open, &closed);    
        }
        /*
        if(x->rightIndex >= 0){
            board *y = x;
            board temp_y(y->rowSize, y->elements);
            y = &temp_y;
            y->moveRight();
            browseNeighbor(goal, y, &open, &closed);
        }*/
    }
}

int main(){
    const int N = 3;
    int testArray[N*N] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,8}; //only need to move 8 to the left to solve
    int target[N*N] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0}; //target state

    board a(N, target);
    board b(N, testArray);
    b.updateIndexes();

    board *goal = &a;
    board *test = &b;

    solve(goal, test);
}
```

Comment: That's a pretty long question and an even longer piece of code.  Most likely people are not going to be willing to invest the time and effort needed to understand what you are asking.  For example you say you are having trouble with the overloaded assignment operator but you don't say what the problem is - wrong result?  too slow?  some sort of exception?  something else?  Ideally you'd post a shorter question about a specific problem with a short program that reproduced the problem described.  Do that and people are more likely to offer a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I am generally not sure about best practices when posting code because in the past I have posted small snippets and then people want to see the whole thing. Perhaps it is not clear but there are essentially two questions: what I am doing wrong with assignment overloading (it seems that there is a problem with reassigning element), and why I am having problems with vector when I push stuff on to it in a function in which it is passed by pointer. I will try to split the code up and make the questions clearer.

Comment: After a good amount of research I found my problem was the destructor, need to set elements = NULL and then delete [] elements.

Answer (score 1):

Some general style comments:

- Try to get rid of the pointers (prefer to use references when passing to functions, std::vector for holding data, and as a last resort a smart pointer).
- Learn about const correctness.

I think the problem is in your solve routine.  You are taking all sorts of pointers to temporary objects which then disappear when the loop goes around again.

Comment: Ok, let me try and change somethings to references. I think what I am thinking is an overloading problem is actually something to do with the pointers in solve.